# Не загружается jQuery при .load

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте . Использовал "`.load`" загружаются дивы но не загружается внутри дива `player` (`jQuery`) .  Как сделать чтобы при ".`load`" загружался `jquery` . Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Выложите ваш скрипт на http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VQmS2/ код нормально не будет отображаться так как это кусок скрипта

Comment: @fikos, так выделите проблему. (вы в div грузите только html (а лучше как я говорил ранее - json) а плеер инициализируйте в success хэндлере

Comment: Столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Решение тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669740/15872
Должно помочь.