# работа js в файле, вставленном через ".load"

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой, если вставляю файл на страницу через такую конструкцию:

```js
$( '.btn' ).click(function() {
  $( '.loadBlock' ).load( 'test.html' );
});
```

То в мобильном браузере скрипты из файла "test.html" не работают, в десктопных браузерах всё нормально..
С чем это может быть связано и как побороть??

Answer (score 0):

сам спросил, сам отвечаю, работает такая конструкция:

```js
$( '.btn' ).click(function() {
  $( '.loadBlock' ).load( 'test.html', function() {
                  // ваш код
  });
});
```

п.с. Но почему не пашет в мобиле исходная конструкция - не понятно.